# Python 3, Tkinter, trying to get 9 buttons on 3 different rows

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Ive just started using tkinter and have this so far:

```
from tkinter import *

BoardValue = ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]

window = Tk()
window.title("Noughts And Crosses")
window.geometry("250x250")

for b in BoardValue[0:3]:
    btn = Button(window, text=b, relief=GROOVE, width=2).pack(side=LEFT)
for b in BoardValue[3:6]:
    btn = Button(window, text=b, relief=GROOVE, width=2).pack(side=LEFT)
for b in BoardValue[6:9]:
    btn = Button(window, text=b, relief=GROOVE, width=2).pack(side=LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```

I want 3 buttons on 3 rows, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common solutions: one using `grid`, and one using `pack` with subframes for each row. There are other solutions but these are the most common. Of these two, when creating a grid of widgets, `grid` is the most natural solution.

Note: in both of the examples below, you can create the buttons in three separate loops if you want, but since the buttons are identical I chose to use a single loop to make the code a little easier to maintain (for example, if you decide to change the relief, you only have to change it in one line of code rather than three).

### Using `grid`

You can use the grid geometry manager to align things in rows and columns. Since you can compute the row and column with simple math, you can reduce all of that code down to something like this:

```
for i, b in enumerate(BoardValue):
    row = int(i/3)
    col = i%3
    btn = Button(window, text=b, relief=GROOVE, width=2)
    btn.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew")
```

You may want to add a weight to the rows and columns if you want them to grow and shrink equally when you resize the window.

`grid` has an advantage over `pack` when building a matrix like this, since each cell is guaranteed to be the same size.

### Using pack

If you know that each button will be the same width, you can use `pack` in combination with subframes. Pack the subframes along the top, and the buttons along the left or right. Again, you can use a little math to know when a new row is starting.

It would look something like this:

```
for i, b in enumerate(BoardValue):
    if i%3 == 0:
        row_frame = Frame(window)
        row_frame.pack(side="top")
    btn = Button(row_frame, text=b, relief=GROOVE, width=2)
    btn.pack(side="left")
```

Using pack may not be the right choice if buttons could be different sizes, since there are no actual columns using this method.

Comment: The Grid one throws up this error: `_tkinter.TclError: bad row value "0.0": must be a non-negative integer`

Comment: @Mrchooch: I'm guessing you're using python3. My apologies, I only tested on 2.x. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to put the buttons in frames so you can control the packing order.  E.g.;

```
i=0
for f in range(3):
    frame[f] = Frame(window).pack(side=TOP)
    for b in range(3):
        btn[i] = Button(frame[f], text=i, relief=GROOVE, width=2).pack(side=LEFT)
        i+=1
```

I've put the button & frame objects into lists in case you need to access the button objects later; you were overwriting your handles in the original code.